# Asp layouts management

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, layout

before I ask my question let me just briefly describe my problem. I maintain a site (e-commerce) which was originally implemented as a website in ASP 2.0. It has a lot of different (a mainly unnecessary) features with different components and similar stuff. It was maintained and developed for many year for a bunch of different people. Recently our client asked about new layouts to the site. Each layout changes site drastically and by that I mean different controls, different position of controls based on layout etc. And now is my question: what is the best way to manage different layout like this? I looked at many solution and each has it drawbacks:

- Ofc we can add many if statements but then code become unreadable cuz it not one one new layout but a coupe of them
- We used master pages but they are on generic level I mean like main menu/side menus/ content so I cannot used them to position single controls
- I tried to create different aspx pages for each layout which point to same code file, but then when I make a change in interface I need to remember to do it on all mirror pages and whats worse I all aspx pages need to used same controls even when in some layout they are not visible
- I could possible position all controls by different css files for each layout but it would be hard and based on fixed positioning which i don't think is a good solution

For now i used different css files for basic styling and if statements in aspx and cs files based on selected layout which makes site really hard to maintain. Can anyone propose some solution? Or maybe some hints how to make it easier to maintain?

Comment: These questions may be a little too broad and will attract opinion based answers. SO is a place to share your code get help with that code when it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit generic, but I thought that someone with experience could give me some tips about managing layout in classic asp

Comment: Are you sure it is Classic ASP? You mention ASPX files and ASP 2.0 so I think you mean ASP.NET. You may want to re-tag your question.

Comment: @John You are right. Didn't see that asp has more tags. Retagged